# Are there any shortcuts to empty cache and hard reload in chrome for devs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, shortcut

I'm trying to find if there are any shortcuts for emptying cache and hard reload shortcuts in chrome instead of console logging and using the empty cache option.

Comment: Ctrl-F5: [What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](//stackoverflow.com/a/385384)

Comment: Disable cache and "Shift + cmd + R" should work ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to leave Dev Tools (F12 / CTRL+SHIFT+I) open, Network tab, check **Disable cache**, next time you reload any which way (click reload icon / CTRL+R / F5) it will do a reload that ALSO isn't cached.

I tested this by updating a source script that without "disabling cache" wouldn't update upon reload alone, or even with Dev Tools open and right-click the reload icon selecting Hard Reload. Would be a great Chrome Extension to make this occur whenever it's enabled though!

Comment: If I had a better rating I could mark this a duplicate. There are a bunch of similar posts if you know what to search for: "chrome disable cache"

Answer (score -1):

## <**Google Chrome**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

## <**Firefox**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: `ctrl`+`shift`+`R` does nothing on macOS.  `command`+`shift`+`R` only hard reloads.